# Adding Foreign Key to Foreign Key Constrained Table

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have this tables:

quotes

```
+---------------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+---+
| Field               | Type                  | Null | Key | Default 
+---------------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+---+
| id                  | int(11) unsigned      | NO   | PRI | NULL    
... (More Columns)           
+---------------------+-----------------------+------+-----+-------------+
```

quotesPackagesInfo

```
+---------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+------------+
| Field         | Type                | Null | Key | Default          
+---------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+------------+
| id            | int(11) unsigned    | NO   | PRI | NULL     
| quoteId       | int(11) unsigned    | NO   |     | NULL    
... (More Columns)
+---------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+------------+
```

quotesFlightsInfo

```
+---------------------------+---------------------+------+-----+----------+
| Field                     | Type                | Null | Key | Default 
+---------------------------+---------------------+------+-----+----------+
| id                        | int(11) unsigned    | NO   | PRI | NULL    
| quoteId                   | int(11) unsigned    | NO   | MUL | NULL                    
| packageId                 | int(11) unsigned    | YES  | MUL | NULL                                    ... (More Columns) 
+---------------------------+---------------------+------+-----+----------+
```

So basically there're quotes which are the main key, after there're packages within a quote, and a package can contain flights, so i need that when a package is removed, all flights related get deleted, so i added a foreign key to flights as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE quotesFlightsInfo
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_quotesFlightsInfo_packageId
FOREIGN KEY (packageId) REFERENCES quotesPackagesInfo(id)
ON DELETE CASCADE
```

now im trying to add a foreign key to packages so when a quote gets deleted also the package deletes and so the flights but isnt working :(, here the query:

```
ALTER TABLE quotesPackagesInfo 
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_quotesPackagesInfo_quoteId 
FOREIGN KEY (quoteId) REFERENCES quotes(id) 
ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Error: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`??????????`.`#sql-312_2`, CONSTRAINT `fk_quotesPackagesInfo_quoteId` FOREIGN KEY (`quoteId`) REFERENCES `quotes` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)

Answer (score 0):

i deleted the quotesPackagesInfo table and created it again adding the foreign key from start and it worked, but still dont know whats was wrong before

Comment: Well, what did the table contain? Also, read the sections in the official documentation re FK constraints, including how get more info. Also please read & act on [mcve].